# API to access GAE services

Tags: google-app-engine

I was wondering if there is an API to access GAE's services including logs, performance, tasks in the queue, something like bulkloader.

Comment: All of App Engine's services are exposed over an API. Are you talking about a way to access them from outside the App Engine environment?

Comment: I wanted to know what these guys (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats) did. I asked the question in their forum; got response that they use ApiProxy to hook to each db calls. I didn't know you could do that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Logging:**

There's no out-of-the-box way to access App Engine logs outside of your App Engine app (which you can do with the [LogService API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/logservice/)). However, there are examples, such as [log2bq](http://code.google.com/p/log2bq/) that export your logs into BigQuery.

**Performance:**

Not sure what type of thing you're looking for here, but if the data is tracked via the logs, you can use the above example. If you can elaborate, perhaps I can better answer you.

**Tasks:**

You can use the [TaskQueue REST API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/rest).

Comment: I found a 3rd party service (http://gaestudio.arcbees.com/) which suggests possible optimizations to GAE applications by simply including a mapping to their Servlet in my web.xml. I was wondering how they were able to access/get the information in order to come up with the optimization suggestions. I was trying to do something similar before, but couldn't find the APIs..

Comment: Parts of it look similar to appstats (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats), but without further investigation I'm not sure how their solution works.

Answer (score 0):

probably not, except there're several [rest APIs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/rest) to access queue tasks.